# How to force passcode unlock on iPhone SE lock screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, unlock

I want to be able to unlock my phone when I’m wearing touch screen compatible gloves. Touch ID doesn’t work with gloves. When I tap the home button to unlock, (sometimes) the phone doesn’t do anything. Just stays on the lock screen. This behavior is inconsistent. 
If I hold down the home button it activates Siri.
When this is happening, it doesn’t matter how much I mash the home button, I cannot get the phone to give me the option to use my passcode. I have to take my gloves off and use Touch ID.

On some occasions there is a tap here to use passcode link but I don’t know what the logic is to get that link to appear.

Any advice?

iPhone SE
iOS 11.2.6

Comment: When I press the home button on Touch ID iPad with a fingernail or stylus, the password screen is shown immediately. Are you wearing capacitive gloves or something that reads close enough to a fingerprint rather Tina pressing the center of the button?

Comment: Yes. Is that the problem?

Comment: Only if you don't want to wait for the 5 or so failed "read" attempts. When TouchID senses something that could be a finger - it tries to read a print. When it knows there's no finger like object - it shortcuts to the PIN/passcode entry.

Comment: This does not happen on my iPad.  When the screen is dark, the button pressure works and the screen lights up.  After that, I must take off a glove so that it can read my finger.  No amount of pressure can get me a number pad to tap on with the Apple Pencil (nor a ten-dollar conductive stylus)  Cheapens the value of the expensive Apple Pencil (although I bought the beast for other reasons).

Comment: I have not tested this on an iPad. Only iPhone SE running iOS 11.2.6.  Older versions of iOS do not support the Widget screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option I just found would be to:

1. Tap home to open lock screen.
2. Swipe right to view app Widgets screen.
3. Tap on an app Widget and you get the version of the unlock screen that has the link to “use passcode”.
4. Tap the “use passcode” link.

Comment: ?? Swipe right does nothing on my I until the screen is unlocked.

Comment: What version of iOS are you using?  see: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207122

Answer (score 1):

Old post. I know. I was bothered with this problem for a loooong long time. Hence, I was looking for solution, while reading this topic here (thanks for that) i !accidently! found the solution:

SOLUTION on iPhone SE (iOS 14.2:

1. press either the home or on/off button ONCE
2. wait a short while (approx. 0,63468 seconds) ;-)
3. press the home button

TOUCH ID or Enter Passcode shows up

OMG, it is so simple. I was so frustrated. Hitting my home button so often, angry about Apple,... Now its all gone. Simple and easy solution.

Comment: This would be for a much newer iPhone SE model and newer iOS version... I don't own that model phone anymore so cannot confirm or deny this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable Touch ID *for your next unlock only* by pressing the power button 5 times, then pressing the home button to exit the power off window. After that, press the home button and enter your passcode to unlock your phone.

**WARNING: Make sure Emergency SOS Auto Call is off in Settings before attempting this.**